# Shell, subshell, source, background process, PID == confusion

Tags: bash, shell, pid

I am trying to get my mind straight as to how all these things are put together. For example with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

. script1
./script2
. script3 &
./script4 &

sleep 5
```

How do the PIDs look like? What is a  separate process and what isn't? Is background process the same as a subshell?

Comment: Seems like you forgot to ask about `source script5` and that was what I was looking for.  Or else you might want to remove 'source' from the title...

Comment: `source` is the same as the standalone-dots I have in the example.

Comment: Wow! [more on that...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25488/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-in-bash)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`. script1` -- not a separate process; script1 is executed in the **current** shell. see `help .`

`./script2` -- just like calling any external command, forks a new process and waits for completion

`. script3 &` -- yes, a separate process. An example:

```
$ cat script3
sleep 300
$ . script3 &
[1] 15136
$ echo $$
15102
$ ps -ef | grep $$
jackman  15102 32659  0 09:43 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
jackman  15136 15102  0 09:44 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
jackman  15157 15102  0 09:44 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
jackman  15158 15102  0 09:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 15102
```

See the bash manual, [Lists of commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell.

`./script4 &` -- yes, a separate process.